# Is it better to finish reading the Quran during Ramadan without understanding it, or understanding it without finishing it?

Tags: ramadan, reading-quran

I am trying to finish the Quran during the month of Ramadan, but I am facing a choice. I am a very beginner in Arabic language, what means, if I try to understand what I read (using a dictionary or using English version alongside). However, if I simply read it without struggling to understand, I may finish it.

What the best option?

Comment: Relevant posts: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32538/reading-quran-even-we-do-not-understand-arabic-during-ramadan/32542#32542 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31422/reading-the-quran-in-ramadan/31427#31427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is already in my linked answers ([Reading Qu'ran even we do not understand Arabic during Ramadan?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32538/reading-quran-even-we-do-not-understand-arabic-during-ramadan) and [Reading the Quran in Ramadan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31422/reading-the-quran-in-ramadan)) reading qur'an while trying to understand it.

There's no need to finish or complete a recitation, as there is no clear backup for that in the sunnah. It is something people made a sunnah lately, as almost all mosques try to complete the qur'an in taraweeh etc. But Allah says:

> Then do they not reflect upon the Qur'an? If it had been from [any] other than Allah , they would have found within it much contradiction. ([4:82](http://legacy.quran.com/4/82))

and in surat Muhammad():

> Then do they not reflect upon the Qur'an, or are there locks upon [their] hearts? ([47:24](http://legacy.quran.com/47/24))

so reflection and therefore understanding the qur'an is asked, recommended and needed while reading it.

On the other hand it is not recommended to read it with haste or struggle ...

> Move not your tongue with it, [O Muhammad], to hasten with recitation of the Qur'an. (16)
>   Indeed, upon Us is its collection [in your heart] and [to make possible] its recitation.
>    ([75:16-17)](http://legacy.quran.com/75/16-17)

But you should read or at least try your best to read and recite  it, as it was revealed ...

> Or add to it, and recite the Qur'an with measured recitation. ([73:4](http://legacy.quran.com/73/4))

in a measured recitation (with tajweed or with no haste and by giving each letter the most corerct intonation etc.).

So the best is to read the qur'an and try to understand it without haste nor struggle, but try to take your time in the pronunciation and try to understand, reflect and think about what you are actually reciting.

Comment: If I understand well, you recommend me to try understanding instead of trying to finish it (while not understanding)?

Comment: @youssouf at least try to reflect it not just reading by passing by