# Should we recite holy Qur'an or read the translation if we get a limited time per day?

Tags: quran-recitation, quran-translation

It is a virtue to recite Quraan in Islam. When I get time to recite holy Quraan, I think whether should I recite it or read the translation to understand the meaning.

Comment: The third option is to do both, but to do it a little at a time, such as a few verses every day.

Comment: Yep, I also agree with you to do both of them.

Comment: Relevant posts: [What does Islam say about reading the Quran in a language other than Arabic?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/406/what-does-islam-say-about-reading-the-quran-in-a-language-other-than-Arabic) and [Is it better to finish reading the Quran during Ramadan without understanding it, or understanding it without finishing it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40444/is-it-better-to-finish-reading-the-quran-during-ramadan-without-understanding-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a tough task to recite Quran as well as translation. You  will try both to do.